# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord.js bot delete a censored message from one channel and log it in an admin channel, this is my code:

```
 msg.channel.send(exampleEmbed1);
 msg.guilds.find("721079782833520651").send("Test")
It says this error:

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
 at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/DShirriff/rebelbot/rebel.js:35:16)
 at Client.emit (events.js:323:22)
 at MessageCreateAction.handle (/Users/DShirriff/rebelbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
 at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/Users/DShirriff/rebelbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) etc.
```

Pls someone help :) im pretty new to discord.js and I can't find the answer in other people's questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.guilds` does not exist.

Did you mean `msg.guild`? If you want to get a channel from that guild you will need to use `msg.guild.channels`

Depending on what version you are using:

v11:

```js
const channel = msg.guild.channels.get("channel_id");
```

v12:

```js
const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get("channel_id");
```

Comment: msg.guilds.cache.find("721079782833520651").send("Test") this? it doesn't work in this way. do I just remove .find all together?

Comment: `.find` uses a callback to find it, if you want to get an element of a collection by id, use `.get("72107....")`, updated my answer

Comment: it says "cannot read property cache of undefined" for msg.guilds.cache.get("721079782833520651").send("Test")

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get a channel or guild? With the `.send()` it looks like the first option, you will need to use `msg.guild.channels` if you want the current guild's channels.

Comment: There were a few contradictions in this post so I got confused, but I think I know what you're going for now. Updated my answer.

Comment: yes, I am trying to make it delete the message in any channel in the server, and send a message in a specific channel for the log. it says msg.guild.channels is not a function

Comment: Why are you envoking `msg.guild.channels`? You need to use `.get` on the collection, and the collection depends on which version you are using, not sure if you saw the edit, but either way re-read my answer.

Comment: tysm! it worked perfectly. the new const thing rly helped

Answer (score 0):

Use that (v12)

```js
let channelID = "channeid";
client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send("Your Text")

// replace channelid to your channel id
```

Easy, No?